# Dynamic pivot in databricks/spark SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, pivot, databricks

When pivoting in SQL (databricks/spark SQL), is there a way to set the "in" part of the for-in dynamically?

For example, this code:

```
select *
from (select office, country, revenue from sales)
pivot (
  sum(revenue)
  for country in ('US', 'CA', 'UK') 
)
```

...works fine, but the `country` column will have different values each month, so I don't want to have to look that up and re-write the code each time. I tried putting `country` and  `select distinct country from sales` in there but these didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: can you add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution to this? We're keen to do something similar.

Comment: @Brendan apologies, I can't remember if I found a solution. It was for a job I'm no longer in anymore, so i can't look up the code either. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: @Brendan any luck finding a solution to this?

Comment: Just following up on any proposed solutions. Surprised they don't support dynamic columns. I may look at pyspark as the examples do not require you to define the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I was just exploring on the same lines and found that there is a work around for that.

First, create a data frame of your table. On data frame you have the capability of dynamic pivot. See code below

```
     %python
     sales_df = sql('select * from sales')
```

> #pivoting and saving in an other df

```
  %python
 sale_pivot = sales_df.groupby( "office", "country", "revenue").pivot("country").sum("revenue")
```

Now if you want to use this with sql syntax change it to sql temp view

```
%python
 
sale_pivot.createOrReplaceTempView("sale_pivotSql")
```

> querying for sql

```
%sql
select * from sale_pivotSql
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm being reduced to string building a query with a dynamically sculpted IN() list.  A bit disappointing. But this technique also means I can dynamically apply reasonable pivoted alias names.
But I'm on the fence whether this is perhaps better done in pyspark -v- Spark SQL